How do I drive a bone's rotation based on another bone's movement?
I am trying to rig a rack and pinion, where the rack is driven by a piston. I have set up the rack/piston using an IK constraint which targets a bone rotating about the central shaft. The highlighted cyan bone represent the movement of the rack/piston. I would like the small bone at the 3D cursor to rotate with the rack's movement.

The problem I am having is that the location data for that bone is greyed out:

I have tried parenting another bone to the cyan piston bone, which does have usable location data. The problem there is that since the data is relative to parent, all of the values just remain permanently at 0.
I understand the math necessary to convert linear motion into rotation. My problem is that I cannot figure out a way to actually access that linear motion in a usable format to power a driver. How can I do that?


Could you use a transform constraint? Or an action constraint?

Good thought! It turns out this is actually doable with the Transformation Constraint (not to be confused with Copy Transform), mapping Location to Rotation. Brilliant
